# Set hover background dynamically with Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

I have Stylus rules for social links:

```
a
    color #fff
    display block
    width @height
    line-height @height
    text-align center
    border-radius (@height/ 2)
    &.fa-facebook
        background #5d82d2
    &.fa-twitter
        background #3dbff1
    &.fa-google
        background #eb5e4c
    &.fa-tumblr
        background #426e9d
    &.fa-linkedin
        background #248cc9
    &.fa-instagram
        background #5389b5
```

They all have different background colors. Now I want each link to change its color to Stylus `lighten(@background, 40%)`. 
How can I do it not copy/pasting it into each item? Should I use mixins or is there a more basic solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash for storing the colors for social links, and then use loop to get all the values including the hover ones, like this:

```
$social-links = {
  facebook: #5d82d2
  twitter: #3dbff1
  google: #eb5e4c
  tumblr: #426e9d
  linkedin: #248cc9
  instagram: #5389b5
}

a
  for $social-link, $social-link-color in $social-links
    &.fa-{$social-link}
      background: $social-link-color

      &:hover
        background: lighten($social-link-color, 40%)
```